# Simple code has error in Xcode: duplicate symbol __ZN4Date8setmonthE

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, duplicates, symbols

I'm new to C++. Trying out a pretty simple problem involving a header file with a class, an implementation.cpp file, and a main .cpp file. Everything works until I run the program, then Xcode gives me this error:

`duplicate symbol __ZN4Date8setmonthEi in:
    /Users/KB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3.15-fdmyzxvsswfgagasdplzankmibai/Build/Intermediates.noindex/3.15.build/Debug/3.15.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/KB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3.15-fdmyzxvsswfgagasdplzankmibai/Build/Intermediates.noindex/3.15.build/Debug/3.15.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/implement.o`

It says this nine times in a row. I don't know what it's trying to tell me. It also says at the bottom of it all:
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Don't know how to fix this, any help would be great, and let me know if you want me to post any of the three files I wrote for this program.

Thanks.

Comment: you define `_Date::setmonth(int)` multiple times, looks like you put definition into a header. Are you sure there are 2 underscores on the symbol? Is your class really have name `_Date`? That's illegal identifier.

Comment: Thats weird because I declare it once in my header file, define it in my implementation file, and call it in the test class. I only define it once. Also, my class name is just Date, just checked and I have no idea where the _ is coming from in the error message.

Comment: error message clearly shows that this symbol is defined in `main.o` and `implement.o` so you need to check your code.

Comment: I figured it out. I was including my implementation file and my header in my main file, where I should only have included my header. Fixed

Comment: .cpp files must never be included indeed. Also you must also protect each header file with the #ifndef preprocessor directive